# Counter only working on the first click for jQuery game

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm new to js and jQuery. I am trying to make a counter go up every time a game is won. But the counter only ever gets up to the number one and then stops. Someone told me that I need to declare the new score outside of the callback function. I tried both ways, outside the function on the if statement and inside on the else statement. I am getting the same result regardless. Was hoping some one can point out where I'm going wrong and how to fix it.

```js
const myApp = {};
// number option callback function
myApp.handleChoiceClick = function() {
  // save selected number from user
  const userNumber = parseInt($(this).val());
  // disable other buttons after choice has been picked
  $('.numberOption').attr('disabled', true);
  // save randomly generate number between zero and five for computer player
  const opponentNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
  // have the chosen number for the user and the computer display on the page with a hand
  const displayHand = function() {
    $(`.evenFinger${userNumber}`).css('z-index', '10');
    $(`.finger${opponentNumber}`).css('z-index', '10');
  };
  displayHand();
  // set score counter to zero
  // compare if even or odd wins by using modulos
  // display "winner"/"lose" on the page if the user wins/loses
  const summedFingers = userNumber + opponentNumber;
  if (summedFingers % 2 === 0) {
    $('.winSum').html(`${summedFingers} fingers`);
    $('.winDeclaration').html('evens wins');
    $(`.playAgain`).css('visibility', 'visible');
    // add score to user
    const userScore = 1;
    myApp.evenScoreUpdate(userScore);
  } else {
    $('.winSum').html(`${summedFingers} fingers`);
    $('.winDeclaration').html('odds wins');
    $(`.playAgain`).css('visibility', 'visible');
    // add score to opponent
    let opponentScore = 0;
    opponentScore += 1;
    $('.oddScore').html(opponentScore);
  }
};
myApp.evenScoreUpdate = function(evenScore) {
  let newscore = 0;
  newscore += evenScore;
  $('.evenScore').html(newscore);
};
// create a play again button the resets the code
myApp.handlePlayAgainClick = function() {
  $('.handReset').css('z-index', '0');
  $('.playAgain').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  $('.winSum').html(' ');
  $('.winDeclaration').html(' ');
  $('.numberOption').attr('disabled', false);
};
// fade in header text on pageload
myApp.headerAnimate = function() {
  $('.hidden').fadeIn(1250).removeClass('hidden');
};
// play again click function
myApp.playAgain = function() {
  $('.playAgain').on('click', myApp.handlePlayAgainClick);
};
// number option click function
myApp.clickNumbers = function() {
  $('.numberOption').on('click', myApp.handleChoiceClick);
};
// initialization
myApp.init = function() {
  myApp.clickNumbers();
  myApp.playAgain();
  myApp.headerAnimate();
};
// pageload
$(function() {
  myApp.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scoreCounter">
  <h2>Even</h2>
  <h2 class="evenScore">0</h2>
  <h2>Odd</h2>
  <h2 class="oddScore">0</h2>
</div>
<div class="optionContainer">
  <button class="numberOption" value="1"><img src="./assets/fingerprint1.png" alt="1"></button>
  <button class="numberOption" value="2"><img src="./assets/fingerprint2.png" alt="2"></button></button>
  <button class="numberOption" value="3"><img src="./assets/fingerprint3.png" alt="3"></button></button>
  <button class="numberOption" value="4"><img src="./assets/fingerprint4.png" alt="4"></button></button>
  <button class="numberOption" value="5"><img src="./assets/fingerprint5.png" alt="5"></button></button>
</div>
<div class="victoryStatement">
  <h2 class="winSum"></h2>
  <h2 class="winDeclaration"></h2>
  <button class="playAgain">Play Again</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the score variables outside the function meaning to define them outside the function:

```js
const myApp = {};
let userScore = 0;
let opponentScore = 0;
...
```

and do not reinitialize them on every `myApp.handleChoiceClick` call. However you'd better add those values as `myApp` object properties and initialize them within the `init` function:

```js
myApp.init = function() {
  myApp.userScore = 0;
  myApp.opponentScore = 0;
  myApp.clickNumbers();
  myApp.playAgain();
  myApp.headerAnimate();
};
```

Use the `++` operator to increment the variable / object property (makes no difference, just a more usual way to do it):

```js
if (summedFingers % 2 === 0) {
  ...
  // add score to user
  myApp.userScore ++;
  $('.evenScore').html(myApp.userScore);
} else {
  ...
  // add score to opponent
  myApp.opponentScore ++;
  $('.oddScore').html(myApp.opponentScore);
}
```

The whole code will be the

```js
const myApp = {};
// number option callback function
myApp.handleChoiceClick = function() {
  // save selected number from user
  const userNumber = parseInt($(this).val());
  // disable other buttons after choice has been picked
  $('.numberOption').attr('disabled', true);
  // save randomly generate number between zero and five for computer player
  const opponentNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
  // have the chosen number for the user and the computer display on the page with a hand
  const displayHand = function() {
    $(`.evenFinger${userNumber}`).css('z-index', '10');
    $(`.finger${opponentNumber}`).css('z-index', '10');
  };
  displayHand();
  // set score counter to zero
  // compare if even or odd wins by using modulos
  // display "winner"/"lose" on the page if the user wins/loses
  const summedFingers = userNumber + opponentNumber;
  if (summedFingers % 2 === 0) {
    $('.winSum').html(`${summedFingers} fingers`);
    $('.winDeclaration').html('evens wins');
    $(`.playAgain`).css('visibility', 'visible');
    // add score to user
    myApp.userScore ++;
    $('.evenScore').html(myApp.userScore);
  } else {
    $('.winSum').html(`${summedFingers} fingers`);
    $('.winDeclaration').html('odds wins');
    $(`.playAgain`).css('visibility', 'visible');
    // add score to opponent
    myApp.opponentScore ++;
    $('.oddScore').html(myApp.opponentScore);
  }
};
// create a play again button the resets the code
myApp.handlePlayAgainClick = function() {
  $('.handReset').css('z-index', '0');
  $('.playAgain').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  $('.winSum').html(' ');
  $('.winDeclaration').html(' ');
  $('.numberOption').attr('disabled', false);
};
// fade in header text on pageload
myApp.headerAnimate = function() {
  $('.hidden').fadeIn(1250).removeClass('hidden');
};
// play again click function
myApp.playAgain = function() {
  $('.playAgain').on('click', myApp.handlePlayAgainClick);
};
// number option click function
myApp.clickNumbers = function() {
  $('.numberOption').on('click', myApp.handleChoiceClick);
};
// initialization
myApp.init = function() {
  myApp.userScore = 0;
  myApp.opponentScore = 0;
  myApp.clickNumbers();
  myApp.playAgain();
  myApp.headerAnimate();
};
// pageload
$(function() {
  myApp.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scoreCounter">
  <h2>Even</h2>
  <h2 class="evenScore">0</h2>
  <h2>Odd</h2>
  <h2 class="oddScore">0</h2>
</div>
<div class="optionContainer">
  <button class="numberOption" value="1"><img src="./assets/fingerprint1.png" alt="1"></button>
  <button class="numberOption" value="2"><img src="./assets/fingerprint2.png" alt="2"></button></button>
  <button class="numberOption" value="3"><img src="./assets/fingerprint3.png" alt="3"></button></button>
  <button class="numberOption" value="4"><img src="./assets/fingerprint4.png" alt="4"></button></button>
  <button class="numberOption" value="5"><img src="./assets/fingerprint5.png" alt="5"></button></button>
</div>
<div class="victoryStatement">
  <h2 class="winSum"></h2>
  <h2 class="winDeclaration"></h2>
  <button class="playAgain">Play Again</button>
</div>
```